# Problem with creating python executor

Tags: python

I have created a `FileManager` for my personal files. The launcher for this manager is launched by following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ui.MovieManager import MovieManager

MovieManager().showView()
```

Movie manager and other modules are situated in the `ui` and `core` packages, but when executing the file as script, I do get following error.

```
vsd@homeworks:~/homework/ws-python/movie-database$ sh Launcher.py 
from: can't read /var/mail/ui.MovieManager
```

I am not able to identify why this script is not picking up `MovieManager` module under the current folder? However when I execute command  `python Launcher.py`, It works well.

Comment: Don't run your script through `sh`; it expects a bash/sh script.

Comment: Yes, You are right. It works without the sh command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not python which generates the error.

Check this out:

```
blubb@nemo:~$ from ui.MovieManager import MovieManager
from: can't read /var/mail/ui.MovieManager
```

Mind you, this is the console, which is a logical consequence of you calling the script with `sh Launcher.py`. Instead, use  `./Launcher.py`. For this to work your file needs to be marked as executable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to the folder where Launcher.py is and running

```
./Launcher.py
```